# MongoDB - descending index weird behavior

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this `test` collection in my `test` database.

```
[test] 2014-02-11 18:01:33.970 >>> db.test.find ();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8a695fa10cc7d2b7908"), "x" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8ab95fa10cc7d2b7909"), "x" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8ad95fa10cc7d2b790a"), "x" : 15 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8b095fa10cc7d2b790b"), "x" : 25 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8b795fa10cc7d2b790c"), "x" : [ 5, 25 ] }
```

If I create an ascending index on the x field with

```
[test] 2014-02-11 18:01:50.615 >>> db.test.createIndex({x : 1});
```

then this find query is working fine and returning the expected result:

```
[test] 2014-02-11 18:01:48.72 >>> db.test.find ( { x : {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } ).min({x:10}).max({x:20});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8ad95fa10cc7d2b790a"), "x" : 15 }
[test] 2014-02-11 18:01:50.615 >>>
```

Buf if drop that ascending index, and then create a descending index with

```
[test] 2014-02-11 18:01:50.615 >>> db.test.createIndex({x : -1});
```

then the same find query is returning this error:

```
error: {
        "$err" : "no index found for specified keyPattern: {} min: { x: 10.0 } max: { x: 20.0 }",
        "code" : 10367
}
```

I was expecting that MongoDB would return the same document here:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8ad95fa10cc7d2b790a"), "x" : 15 }
```

This sounds illogical to me.
Why is that? Why is MongoDB not able to use that descending index on x?

[create index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)
[drop index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/)
[get indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/list-indexes/)

Comment: You might try adding an explicit index hint. Also mongo being kinda iffy in terms of validation I wouldn't be surprised if reversing your min and max order fixes it.

Comment: I think it doesn't, I tried swapping them as I had the same initial guess for a quick fix.

Comment: What do you mean by explicit index hint? Could you point me to some reference?

Comment: I was referring to this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/

Comment: That doesn't work because you are using min and max in ascending order, min and max are extremely special

Comment: Is there a way to use them in desc order? I mean, by using just them can I modify this query and get it working when the index on x is desc?

Comment: @peter.petrov swap min and max around should work

Comment: This does not work: db.test.find ( { x : {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } ).max({x:20}).min({x:10}); This works though: db.test.find ( { x : {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } ).max({x:10}).min({x:20}); Wow !!!

Comment: @Sammaye max=10 min=20 and it works !!! :) That's funny. But thank you. This is basically what I was looking for. Not that I can explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
> db.h.insert({x:15})
> db.h.createIndex({x:-1})
> db.h.find().min({x:20}).max({x:10})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fb6930253ac3dcf43b27f5"), "x" : 15 }
```

Your index might have a problem with it.

The reason this works is because the index is the other way around.

Imagine you turn a list on its head, what min and max effectively say is get a range of that list with the min being 10 and max being 20. However that range no longer exists since the list is upside down. Instead the range must be reversed to match the list.

Comment: No, my index has no problem. It works the same way. This does work. Thanks again.

Comment: If you could elaborate a bit why it works that would make a really tremendous answer.

Comment: @peter.petrov Because the index is in refverse order `min` is the ASC value so to speak and `max` is the desc value, if you reverse the index is cannot find that range because it doesn't exist

Comment: So it's like saying - the interval [10,20] and the interval [20,10], the second one is of course empty. Yes, I got it. I ran explain() and I got it. Thank you. `db.test.find ( { x : {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } ).max({x:10}).explain();` and ` db.test.find ( { x : {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } ).min({x:20}).explain();`

Comment: @peter.petrov yes, this is of course because min and max actually clips to the index, it is quite different to gte and lte etc, it actually limits the index itself

Comment: Yes, the book says so too. Thank you. I just thought that 10 and 20 should be given to min and max respectively, no matter of the index direction. I thought MongoDB would take the 10 and 20 values, and order them as needed (in order to use the index later). But it is not that way.

Comment: @peter.petrov indeed not, MongoDB technically has no way of kniowing if 10 is less than 20 when considering what data could be in the index etc so it just provides a direct conduict for you to input it, think of it as bypassing all those checks and saftey measures to get what you want

Comment: Funny thing. I wonder how it will behave if you have two indexes asc and desc. I guess there's no ambiguity then.

Comment: Got it, OK, OK. Thanks a bunch once more!

Comment: @peter.petrov Hmm I have never tried it actually but I would bet it would still error out since it doesn't provide the checks but in the case of a compound index there shouldn't be ambiquity unless cardinality is such that two or more fields would have duplicates within the same index entry

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it's not weird at all ( You seem to be asking lots of questions stating "weird" behavior ) if you actually look at what you are doing.

As you said you **changed the order** of you index to be descending. So lets look at the results of the query in stages:

```
> db.test.find ( { x : {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8b795fa10cc7d2b790c"), "x" : [  5,  25 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8ad95fa10cc7d2b790a"), "x" : 15 }
```

So there's your first result with the only documents matching your criteria. So let's look at the next stage and also the output of explain:

```
> db.test.find ( { x : {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } ).min({x :10})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8b795fa10cc7d2b790c"), "x" : [  5,  25 ] }
> db.test.find ( { x : {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } ).min({x :10}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor x_-1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 3,
    "nscanned" : 3,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "start" : {
                    "x" : 10
            },
            "end" : {
                    "x" : {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                    }
            }
    },
    "server" : "ubuntu:27017"
}
```

Here we can see the result containing your row with the *array* value in **x**. This is the important part where you need to look at the `indexBounds` as shown in the explain output. You can see that the bounds start at 10, which was your request, and end at the **minimum** result from from the array element. Which despite your lack of projection in the document, has actually given you the answer, **5**.

So when you start of to modify again, looking for a result that is outside of the indexBounds, query goes **boom**. You messed up and asked for something that doesn't exist.

Now if you were **expecting** to get this back as a result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8b795fa10cc7d2b790c"), "x" : [  25 ] }
```

Well the answer is that things just do not work that way. As explained you already reduced the set in the first **min** operation. It's done.

Comment: I don't have such document with { "x" : [ 25 ] }. I was expecting to get this back: { "x" : 15 } i.e. I was expecting to get the same document back (which I got when my index was ascending). I didn't get much of your reply on 1st reading, will reread it a bit later. Still thank you for this reply. Note that I am a beginner in MongoDB. And I do find this weird. Will reread and rethink your answer later.

Comment: @peter.petrov you should give it a re-read, it was clear that you were not getting the purpose of the **min** and **max** cursor modifiers. Look and try to understand the `explain` output. If you *still don't get it* ask another question with your data and expected result, as in "How do I get what I expect?" and then someone can answer.

Comment: I think this is the key part. "You can see that the bounds start at 10, which was your request, and end at the minimum result from from the array element. Which despite your lack of projection in the document, has actually given you the answer, 5." Btw, I don't know what is projection of a document.

Comment: @peter.petrov Doesn't matter what you were expecting to get back. The index bounds after the first **min** in the result are the problem. It's **not** the same in reverse. It's not a sort order, as that would be post processing

Comment: OK, thanks. I think you have a few typos though. Not sure what answer 5, you mean, etc. Will definitely reread it (several times). Thank you.

Comment: And I have no idea where this `"$minElement" : 1` comes from. I would rather expect to see: `"$maxElement" : 1` in the explain result. I told him - go scan your index from min=10 (this implies I want to leave the other/max end open which should default to MongoDB scanning all the way up to the max element, at least that's what my common sense tells me). So OK, again thank you for your answer but this is a rather counter-intuitive behavior IMHO.

Comment: @peter.petrov I told you where $minElement comes from. You used the **min** cursor modifier and that's what it does. **You** are expecting it to do something different. As I said before a **new** question on stack overflow as I proposed will clear this up. You already have the answer to your **question** here. It's not weird, that's how it works. But there is a way to return the answer you want always. Just not how you are approaching looking at it.

Comment: @peter.petrov And it's not counter intuitive. **You** are taking the wrong approach to the answer you want.

Comment: @peter.petrov I think I'll actually post your **real** question and self answer it. Send you the link and that way you might understand why this answer is right and your approach is wrong.

Comment: I thanked you several times. Stop saying my approach is wrong and I messed up, OK? I am just learning MongoDB by reading this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028031.do and on page 63, it says: "Now this will only traverse the index from 10 to 20, missing the 5 and 25 entries. You can only use min() and max() when you have an index on the field you are querying for, though, and you must pass all fields of the index to min() and max()." It does not say the index needs to be ascending or descending. I experimented with both index types and found this weird (to me) behavior. OK?

Comment: @peter.petrov I'm not trying to insult you but you are doing the wrong thing. Follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725130/query-returns-more-than-expected-results

Comment: This is what inspired my question. I understand your answer but I still don't get why it behaves that way and why explain returns what it returns. Thank you once more.

Comment: @peter.petrov Um. That's my question that I put up because it was the one you didn't ask before plunging into **min** and **max** on the cursor. I suppose we could chat about this but I think you would benefit from seeing how that question resolves. Your behavior with **min** and **max** modifiers fails for exactly the reasons I have explained.

Comment: Sure, let's see how the other question resolves. Thanks for formulating it.

Comment: @peter.petrov Good. It should make good reading. I'm waiting on some people @ MongoDB that I know to chime in. Nonetheless your question here as it stands is a good question, as to why things fail using the methods you did. And hence my up-vote.