# Query returns more than expected results

Tags: mongodb

Bear with me, this is not really my question. Just trying to get someone to understand.

**Authors note:**

> The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966203/mongo-query-question-gt-lt) question solution allows $elemMatch to constrain because >**all** of the elements are an array. This is a little different.
>
> So, in the accepted answer the main point has been brought up. This behavior **is well
>   documented** and you **should not** *"compare 'apples'` with 'oranges'"*. The fields are of 
>   different types, and while there is a workaround for this, the best solution for the real
>   world is **don't do this**.
>
> Happy reading :)

I have a collection of documents I am trying to search, the collection contains the following:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8a695fa10cc7d2b7908"), "x" : 1 }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8ab95fa10cc7d2b7909"), "x" : 5 } 
 { "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8ad95fa10cc7d2b790a"), "x" : 15 }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8b095fa10cc7d2b790b"), "x" : 25 }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8b795fa10cc7d2b790c"), "x" : [ 5, 25 ] }
```

So I want to find the results where **x** falls between the values of `10` and `20`. So this is the query that seemed logical to me:

```
db.collection.find({ x: {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} })
```

But the problem is this returns two documents in the result:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8ad95fa10cc7d2b790a"), "x" : 15 }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("52faa8b795fa10cc7d2b790c"), "x" : [ 5, 25 ] }
```

I am not expecting to see the second result as none of the values are between `10` and `20`.
 Can someone explain why I do not get the result I expect? I think **{ "x": 15 }** should be the only document returned.

So furthermore, how can I get what I expect?

Comment: This is a deliberate reference to the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715121/mongodb-descending-index-weird-behavior) but it has been worded as the actual question that the poster is not asking. Their question has been answered in it's context, but an answer to this part clears up the issue for anyone who asks something similar. Let's see who gets it right.

Comment: Its because MongoDB doesn't filter subdocuments

Comment: It does filter subdocuments, but not like this :)

Comment: You can use elemMatch or the aggregation framework but elemMatch will only return the first match and the aggregation framework might be just as slow as actually doing it in the application

Comment: @kocko Go on. Why? Questions need answers not comments. I am deliberately **not** self answering. On consideration that this is a good learning exercise. Real world stuff too.

Comment: @Sammaye. Aggregation? *Maybe*. I think there might be a great big gotcha in there though. If you have an **answer** then post it.

Comment: What if we had a document with x:[11,14]? shouldn't the answer return that document too?

Comment: This is my question. You cannot do it with $elemMatch as this will miss documents having non-arrays for x.

Comment: @peter.petrov you would be better off filtering client side

Comment: "it has been worded as the actual question that the poster is not asking" Neil thinks he knows better what's in my head than I do, but I doubt that. See my comments below Kocko's answer. This is what I am actually asking. I don't want to just get this working somehow. I need to understand why having asc/desc indexes on x make this query behave differently: `db.test.find ( { x : {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } ).min({x:10}).max({x:20});` That's all basically.

Comment: If I have an asc or desc sorted array and I tell him - give me the elements between 10 and 20, it will give me the same elements. It won't error out if it's sorted desc and work OK if it's sorted asc.

Comment: @NeilLunn cos tbh I am unsure of exactly whats being asked, the related seem perfectly normal to me with that OP expecting for index operators of min and max to act the same between different indexes and this question to seem like a simple answer of get them out client side

Comment: @peter.petrov You CANT get that working, min and max are actually index scanning, you change the order of the index you must change the order of the min and max...why are you even using min and max?

Comment: @peter.petrov Ok so we are back to this question now that related has been answered, so what are we actually looking to do here?

Comment: Ok I see the real problem here and yes everyone else doesn't get it one bit, the real problem being that range queries are done in parts on subodcument elements

Comment: Correction Jinxcat gets it but they have no viable work around, I definitely wouldnt advise the query by Kocko, its not correct

Comment: @Sammaye I don't want to interrupt here, but could you possibly comment on my answer how I have "no viable work around"? I would really welcome some constructive criticism :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongo Query question $gt,$lt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966203/mongo-query-question-gt-lt)

Comment: @WiredPrairie Yes, possible but dealing with a slightly different issue of where **all** the elements are an array.

Comment: I think the other question and excellent answer from a MongoDb employee explained the issue well enough.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I think the question and answer serves good as a reference but it is not exactly a duplicate as the cause is different. I had actually forwarded the question to some MongoDB to see if they wanted to chime in. But as it stands your answer is the most complete to date in that it clearly brings up the point, you should not compare apples with oranges. Hence the accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is expected and explained in mongo documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-a-field-that-contains-an-array).

> *Query a Field that Contains an Array*
>
> If a field contains an array and your query has multiple conditional
>   operators, the field as a whole will match if either a single array
>   element meets the conditions **or** *a combination of array elements
>   meet the conditions*.

Mongo seems to be willing to play "smug", by giving back results when a combination of array elements match all conditions independently.

In our example, 5 matches the $lt:20 condition and 25 matches the $gt:10 condition. So, it's a match.

Both of the following will return the [5,25] result:

```
db.collection.find({ x: {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} })

db.collection.find({ $and : [{x: {$gt: 10}},{x:{ $lt: 20}} ] })
```

If this is user expected behaviour, opinions can vary. But it certainly is documented, and should be expected.

**Edit**, for Neil's sadistic yet highly educational edit to original answer, asking for a solution:

Use of the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) can make "stricter" element comparisons for **arrays only**.

```
db.collection.find({ x: { $elemMatch:{ $gt:10, $lt:20  } } })
```

*Note*: this will match both x:[11,12] **and** x:[11,25]

I believe when a query like this is needed, a combination on **two** queries is required, and the results combined. Below is a query that returns correct results for documents with x being **not an array**:

```
db.collection.find( { $where : "!Array.isArray(this.x)", x: {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } )
```

**But the best approach** in this case is to change the type of x to **always** be an array, even when it only contains one element. Then, only the $elemMatch query is required to get correct results, with expected behaviour.

Comment: Good answer. Glad you edited with more info. But, well I'll add one piece to the question that makes the obvious sense.

Comment: @kocko I only saw it after I posted my answer, posted 1 min earlier :) and smiled that we both got there :) don't know if I should thank or hate Neil for this problem! :P Definitely taught me something though :)

Comment: Basically only the last fragment gives a real answer, where you use $where. I don't want to use $where.

Comment: @peter.petrov Actually, I disagree. See edited answer.

Comment: ElemMatch won't work with this data set and the JS version will omit array based fields even if they do actually compound match the range, plus it is actually a full collection scan and a js isolate for every document which is not viable

Comment: @Sammaye hence my conclusion that the problematic case's roots lie in the deficiency of the schema, which should be changed

Comment: Yes but the question is how to query that schema not another, as such changing the schema, especially if data pre-exists is not a workaround but a complete redo of the problem.

Comment: So, when one corners oneself into a problematic situation, we analyse the problem and point its root, or do we point names and name fingers? :) Mongo is showing expected behaviour, even in the "original" question. I can not in good sense not point out that instead of inefficient exercise in schema design *and/or adaptability* it is a problem with a) indexes, b) internal functionality, c) lack of functionality, or a combination thereof.

Comment: You asked why I said you didn't have a workaround and I answered, redoing the schema, unless the schema is still in the planning stage is not a workaround

Comment: I understand your argument, and accept your point of view. However, I don't completely agree on schema in mongo production deployments being set in concrete; that's the equivalent of pretty much saying "no alter statements allowed in RDBMSs". It's an option, at the user's discretion.

Answer (score 2):

You can first check if the subdocument is **not** and array and provide a filter for the desired values:

```
db.collection.find(
  { 
    $and : 
      [
        { $where : "!Array.isArray(this.x)" }, 
        { x: { $gt: 10, $lt: 20 } }
      ]
  }
)
```

which returns:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("52fb4ec1cfe34ac4b9bab163"), "x" : 15 }
```

Comment: Note that the query in its current form will do a full collection scan, also the $and is not needed

Comment: I don't want to use $where. The book I am reading says it's inefficient usually. Page 63-66 here: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028031.do

Comment: See also my original question and the comments below the only answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715121/mongodb-descending-index-weird-behavior/

Comment: My original question was: provided an ascending index ensures the query works, why descending index does not?! I find that weird.

Comment: I mean this query `db.test.find ( { x : {$gt: 10, $lt: 20} } ).min({x:10}).max({x:20});`

Comment: By "works" I mean returns only this document with { "x" : 15 }